# How do I update blog post in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a blog site using CRUD operations. I can create, read and delete but I am having hard time with updating a created post.

Basically I have it where I can click on the "edit" button on an individual entry in **home.ejs** and into the **edit.ejs** route where that input fields are populated with current title and content. But what I can not figure out is clicking "Publish" in **edit.ejs** to update its own **post.ejs** title and content. When it is done, I want to redirect it back to the main page. Down on the "app.post("/edit/:id")" route, am I supposed to use "PUT" request to update the post?

I am sorry if this is tough to follow. I am not very good at explaining things.

Here's the relevant code:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blogDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const postSchema = {
  date: String,
  title: String,
  content: String
}

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

  Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
    res.render("home", {
      posts: posts
    });
  });
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", {
    aboutContent: aboutContent
  });
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact", {
    contactContent: contactContent
  });
});

app.get("/compose", (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose");
});


app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
  const postBody = req.body.postBody;

  let date = new Date();
  let postDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US');

  const post = new Post({
    date: postDate,
    title: postTitle,
    content: postBody
  });

  post.save(err => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body);
  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body);
  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});



app.get("/posts/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;

  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedId
  }, (err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("post", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
  const deletePost = req.body.delete;

  Post.findByIdAndDelete(deletePost, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**home.ejs**

```
    <%- include("partials/header") -%>
<h1>Home</h1>
<a href="/compose" class="post-link"><button type="button" class="new-entry btn btn-dark">New Entry</button></a>

<div class="entries-container">
  <% posts.forEach(post => { %>

  <div class="blog-entry">
    <p class="post-date">Posted on
      <%= post.date %>
    </p>
    <h2>
      <%= post.title %>
    </h2>
    <div class="entry-footer">
      <a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>" class="post-link"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">VIEW</button></a>
      <form action="/edit" method="POST">
        <a href="/edit/<%= post._id %>" class="post-link" ><button type="button" name="edit" value="<%= post.title %>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">EDIT</button></a>
      </form>
      <form action="/delete" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="delete" value="<%= post._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

**edit.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
<h1>Compose</h1>
<form action="/edit" method="PUT">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="postTitle" class="form-control" id="postTitle" autocomplete="off" value="<%= title %>">
    <label for="postBody">Post</label>
    <textarea name="postBody" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" rows="8"><%= content %></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>
<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

**post.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>
  <h2 class="post-title"><%= title %></h2>
  <p class="post-content"><%= content %></p>
<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply update your existing blog post title and content with sending POST request then you can do it with [findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) as below:

```
app.post("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  const requestedId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body);
  Post.findOneAndUpdate({
     _id: requestedId                   // Query Part
  },
  {
    $set: {
       title: req.body.title,           // Fields which we need to update
       content: req.body.content
    }
  },
  { 
     new: true                          // option part ( new: true will provide you updated data in response )
  },(err, post) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("edit", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to update the post by clicking the "Publish" button, it gives me a "Cannot POST /edit" error. I'm trying to have it redirect to the root route after it's been updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: That's all it says. If you have a free AWS Cloud 9 account, I can share with you my project and all the files. I just need your username for Cloud 9.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have account on it.